# The ListBox on the GridView will fire in RowUpdating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want the `ListBox` on the `GridView` to fire in `RowUpdating`. When the user changes the `ListBox`, I want it to postback and give me the row index or data key or filename of the column on that row. I searched the Web and could not find an example or clue to make it work. Hope someone can help me.

Here is my `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView
   ID="grdFilesList"
   runat="server"
   GridLines="None"
   AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"
   AutoGenerateColumns="false"
   DataKeyNames="FileName"
   BorderColor="White"
>
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField
         DataField="FileName"
         HeaderText="Files"
         HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true"
         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
      />
      <asp:BoundField
         DataField="Date"
         HeaderText="Date"
         HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true"
         DataFormatString="{0:d MMM yyyy}"
         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
      />
      <asp:ButtonField
         Text="Delete"
         ControlStyle-BackColor="Black"
         CommandName="Delete"
         ItemStyle-ForeColor="White"
         ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
      />
      <asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox runat="server"ID="lst"></asp:ListBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you're looking for RowDataBound for the GridView and inside of that handler you should add an event handler for the listbox (there are lots of listbox events - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) - see http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/132643/Textbox-change-event-inside-gridview for example.

Comment: There is an extra `<asp:TemplateField>` in your markup. I have left it there to not change the meaning of what you posted.

Comment: Where do you do the data binding for the ListBox? On `RowDataBound`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are missing the `AutoPostBack="true"` for your `ListBox`. Also add an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event so you can capture the selected value or any other control value in that gridview row.

Change your `TemplateField` definition as below

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lst" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lst_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add the below event handler in your code behind (C#)

```
protected void lst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ListBox listBox1 = (ListBox)sender;
   string selectedText = listBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
   string selectedValue = listBox1.SelectedValue;

   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)listBox1.NamingContainer; // selected row
   int rowindex = row.RowIndex; // row index for the selected row

   string fileName = row.Cells[0].Text; // filename value using cell index
   string fileName1 = gvTest.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["FileName"].ToString(); // Retrieve filename value using DataKeys
}
```

Here is the `VB.NET` equivalent (I used a tool to convert, hope it got it correct)

```
Protected Sub lst_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim listBox1 As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Dim selectedText As String = listBox1.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim selectedValue As String = listBox1.SelectedValue

    ' selected row
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(listBox1.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    ' row index for the selected row
    Dim rowindex As Integer = row.RowIndex

    ' filename value using cell index
    Dim fileName As String = row.Cells(0).Text

    ' Retrieve filename value using DataKeys
    Dim fileName1 As String = gvTest.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("FileName").ToString()

End Sub
```